# Sorting an array into a 2nd array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to make 2 arrays and sort one into the other in ascending order and display it. I've managed to move ar[] into sorted[], but I can't get it to actually sort.
Here's what I have so far:

```
public class SortArray
{
    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        int ar[] = { 7, 5, 2, 8, 4, 9, 6 };
        int sorted[] = new int[7];

        for (int i=0; i<ar.length-1; i++)
        {
            int smallest = 1000000;
            int index    = 0;

            for (int j=i+1; j<sorted.length; j++)
            {
                if (ar[i] < smallest)
                {
                    smallest=i;

                    int tmp = ar[i];
                    ar[i] = sorted[j];
                    sorted[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<sorted.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("sorted[" + i + "] = " + sorted[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of sort algorithms. Use google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to understand and use java algorithms here. If you have problems with understanding the idea please do not hesitate to ask.
http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/

They are more efficient and they are not error prone.

Assuming that you are trying to learn sorting algorithms and coding, here is what you are trying to; Please be aware that if there are identical values it will get only one of them.

```
    int ar[] = { 7, 5, 2, 8, 4, 9, 6 };
    int sorted[] = new int[6];

    int smallestFound=-1;
    for (int i=0; i<ar.length-1; i++)
    {
        int smallest = 1000000;
        for (int j=0; j<sorted.length; j++)
        {
            if (ar[j] < smallest && ar[j]>smallestFound) {
                smallest = ar[j];
            }
        }
        smallestFound=smallest;
        sorted[i] = smallest;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<sorted.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("sorted[" + i + "] = " + sorted[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  a [TreeSet](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/TreeList.html) , it sort the element naturally:

```
public class SortArray
{
    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        int ar[] = { 7, 5, 2, 8, 4, 9, 6 };
  int sorted[] = new int[7];
List<Integer> sortedList = new TreeSet<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<ar.length-1; i++) {
    sortedList.add(ar[i]);
}

// transform into array

for(int i = 0; i< sortedList.size(); i++) {
 sorted[i] = sortedList.get(i)
}


        for(int i=0; i<sorted.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("sorted[" + i + "] = " + sorted[i]);
        }
    }
}
```